# Dial multiple ussd simultanously in programme

Tags: android

I'm new in android and I'm developping an application  to execute **ussd (mmi code)** store in data base.

I already have code to execute ussd throuth a service one by one after 30 seconde, it work find but the problem is that there are many ussd and I need to optimaze the programme.

My question is: It's there possible to **execute many ussd simultanously** (programmatically)? If possible, how can I do it?

*Excuse me for my poor english skill*

Thanks!

Comment: Would any of the phone state listener capabilities let you know when the previous is done?  Not saying that they would, but I think it would be a path worth investigating.

Comment: I have searched without result how to detect the end of ussd execution.

Comment: I was suggesting you *run experiments* and see if the phone state correlated with the ussd running/completed.